# How to add unique constraint to existing table in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have an existing table in Sqlite. How do I add a unique constraint to it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am assuming you are using SQLiteManager from FireFox, please create the table again, normally it doesn't allow to change the constraints when you have already created a table.

**NOTE** - It can be done using code too, this is another way of doing it..

Edited
See the image below

[image]

Comment: there is no option for constraints when we create table again too

Comment: come on man question is how to put unique constraint i know they are constraints

Comment: i am not using Sqlite Manager From fireFox i am using Sqlite database browser let me download fire fox thing if they are providing something  like you saying

Comment: Download Firefox and search for extension SQLiteManager and install it, after installing you can find it in Tools menu ..

Answer (score 41):

**You can't add a constraint to existing table in SQLite**,(In SQL there is a option for do that). You need to re-create the table with necessary contraints.

There is only a few option available for alter table command in sqlite. Please check the image:

[image: Alter table]

Also check [Sqlite org](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) reference.

---

#### EDIT

However you can add unique index for your table to achieve the same effect.
So you can use the following query to achieve that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX your_unique_index ON your_table(column_name);
```

> In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by
> creating a unique index in the database.

Reference : [SQLite Constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints)

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes, of course. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @downvoter: I would like to know the reason for your down vote, so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: @rogerdpack :) Thanks for letting me know, thanks for helping me to improve my answer :) Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 16):

You can add constraint by creating unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_friend_name ON friend(name);
```

where `ux_friend_name` is unique index name, `friend(name)` - table and its columns that will be affected by this constraint.

You can read more [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints).