# Muiltples insert using executeSql

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic2

I need to do multiple inserts and I do not know what's wrong. See:

```
 db.openDatabase({
      name: "data.db",
      location: "default"
    }).then(() => {
      db.executeSql(
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Pneus - calibragem'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Pneus – banda de rodagem'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Nivel do oleo'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Luzes dianteiras'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Luzes traseiras'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Triangulo de sinalizacao'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Chave de roda'); "
        +"INSERT INTO check_item (name) VALUES ('Documentacao do veiculo'); ", {}).then((data) => {
          console.log("TABLE CREATED: ", data);
        }, (error) => {
          console.error("Unable to execute sql teste", error);

        })
    }, (error) => {
      console.error("Unable to open database", error);
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: And what is problem?

Comment: @rkosegi Does not insert into bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently trying to execute multiple insertion statements within a single call to `executeSql()`.  The syntax for inserting multiple records in a single statement is:

```
INSERT INTO check_item (name)
VALUES ('Pneus - calibragem'),
       ('Pneus – banda de rodagem'),
       ('Nivel do oleo'),
       ...
       ('Documentacao do veiculo');
```

If you want to prevent the possibility of inserting a name which already exists, the easiest way to do this is perhaps to add a unique constraint on the `name` column.  While it isn't possible to do this in SQLite without recreating the table, we can add a unique index to get the same effect:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_index ON check_item (name);
```

Further reading: [How to add unique constraint in already made table in sqlite ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497985/how-to-add-unique-constraint-in-already-made-table-in-sqlite-ios)

Comment: Thank u. I would like to insert only if the record is not present. How can I do this?

Comment: So at the time of creating the table I should put the "name" as unique, right?

Comment: Yes, add this line to your `CREATE TABLE` statement: `CONSTRAINT name_constraint UNIQUE (name)`

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);