# Adapt ON CONFLICT clause to new unique index?

Tags: sqlite

I want to add an extra unique constraint to an existing table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15498225/7050476) and other answers say it's not possible with sqlite, and suggest creating an unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN new_unique TEXT;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX new_unique_index ON example(new_unique);
```

This seems to work. However, I'm having trouble with `UPSERT`s:

```
INSERT INTO example (foo, old_unique, new_unique) VALUES ('foo', 'old', 'new') ON CONFLICT(old_unique, new_unique) DO UPDATE SET foo='foo';
```

This gives an error:

```
ON CONFLICT cause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
```

Is there any way I could adapt the `ON CONFLICT` clause of the statement above to work with the new "constraint"?

I tried using `new_unique_index`, to no avail. If it's impossible, is there any alternative to creating a new table with the new unique constraint and copying the values from the old table into the new one with NULL for the new constraint column? This would be burdensome. I imagine I could create a new table with all of the former's columns, except the old uniques, plus the new unique, and link them somehow, but it sounds messy and I have no idea how to proceed.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (foo TEXT, old_unique TEXT, UNIQUE(old_unique));
ALTER TABLE example ADD COLUMN new_unique TEXT;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX new_unique_index ON example(new_unique);
INSERT INTO example (foo, old_unique, new_unique) VALUES ('foo', 'old', 'new') ON CONFLICT(old_unique, new_unique) DO UPDATE SET foo='foo';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I could adapt the ON CONFLICT clause of the statement above to work with the new "constraint"?

(old_unique, new_unique) is a not a possible constraint target as there is no index that combines both columns, each is an individual constraint (so you could use one or the other, as my understanding is that you are limited to a single UPSERT clause and a single conflict target).

If instead of :-

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX new_unique_index ON example(new_unique);
```

You used

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX new_unique_index ON example(old_unique,new_unique);
```

Then the following will work :-

```
INSERT INTO example (foo,old_unique,new_unique) VALUES('foo','old','new') ON CONFLICT (old_unique,new_unique) DO UPDATE SET foo = 'foo';
```

*(well at least not be rejected due to no covering primary key or index for the given conflict target).*

> If it's impossible, is there any alternative to creating a new table with the new unique constraint and copying the values from the old table into the new one with NULL for the new constraint column? This would be **burdensome**.

It's not really burdensome e.g. you could use :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_example (foo, old_unique,new_unique, UNIQUE(old_unique,new_unique));
INSERT INTO temp_example SELECT *,null FROM example;
ALTER TABLE example RENAME TO old_example;
ALTER TABLE temp_example RENAME TO example;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS old_example;
```

- i.e. as you are adding a column and it will be the last column then there is no need to code column names.

Comment: The index creation and the UPSERT above worked. However, when working with the actual table I could not make the UPSERT work - the values were not being inserted into the new column. I could not reproduce this on the minimal example I've supplied. I ended up creating a new table as suggested. Thanks.