# Why does using the ALTER COLUMN command return an error?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's a screenshot of my commands and db. I'm working in Sqlite3.
[image: SQLITE 3 commands]

Everything seems fine and I can't see any issues with my command, but I still get an error. Any advice?

Comment: SQLite doesn't support ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN:   https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html.

Comment: You can't add unique constraints to existing tables in SQLite, though you can add a unique index for equivalent functionality... 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497985/how-to-add-unique-constraint-to-existing-table-in-sqlite-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use two command lines Define the first line of the column and the second line create a unique constraint for it.

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD username VARCHAR(30);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX accounts_unique_index ON accounts (username);
```